# Converting latin characters to UTF-8 in URLS in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having problems resolving file names in Wordpress.

Some of the file names have special characters (é ã à) and the files are not showing in posts. like: http://jornaltribunadonorte.com.br/telecentros-oferecem-400-vagas-para-cursos-gratuitos/

Wordpress resolves the filename as:
//jornaltribunadonorte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Aula-de-hardware-Telecentro-Pinda-Cr%C3%A9ditos-Divulga%C3%A7%C3%A3o-258x460.jpg

The file IS stored in the server and can be seen at:
//jornaltribunadonorte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Aula-de-hardware-Telecentro-Pinda-Cr%e9ditos-Divulga%e7%e3o.jpg

How can I make Wordpress resolve the filename as showed in the 3rd link via .htacess?
My .htacess file content is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```